# Is the usage of "and till" appropriate?

Tags: meaning

Is the usage of "**and till**" appropriate?

Personally I think it's not correct since "**till**" is a conjunction and should not be preceded by "**and**". But I noticed such usage in many examples in many circumstances.

> In those days, and till comparatively recent time, the country was densely wooded

Comment: I don't think "until/till" or whatever is even acting as a conjunction in your example sentence.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the use of 'and tilll"; till is a preposition in the sentence.

Comment: I’d avoid it entirely & use ‘and until’ instead. It just sounds forced, to my ear.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, *till* is a contraction or alternate form of *until*, which in this case is a preposition. See sense 3 of the definition [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/until):

> 3. (often preceded by up) in or throughout the period before   ⇒ *he waited until six*

Answer (score 0):

Note that *till* in your sentence is a preposition, not a conjunction. Nevertheless, to address you broader concern: Sometimes conjunctions can be preceded by *and*.

And so (that) he could get a better job, he graduated from high school.

And now that he graduated he started to work.

He liked his professors, the staff, the girls he banged.  And  yet he hated his roommate.

He didn't know how fortunate he was  and till he found out he was miserable.

For *until* (which *till* is a variant of) as both a preposition and conjunction, see [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/until).

Answer (score -1):

*Until* is both a preposition and conjunction.  *And 'til X* is OK if X is a noun or noun phrase.

---

It's common in speech to omit the *un-* part of *until* when speaking quickly or informally.

This is most correctly spelled in writing as *'til*, or *til* which prevents confusion with *till* (meaning a garden tool or part of a cash register).

It's not common in educated or formal writing to contract this word.  You should avoid doing so unless you're writing a fiction book and expressing such speech or in an informal situation.

Comment: 'Till' is an *older* word than 'until', which derives from it in the same way 'unto' derives from 'to'. The proper spelling is *not* ''til'.